# How to detect if some application works certain time interval

Tags: .net

*I have some WPF Client to RIA Services.*

That Client periodicaly does requests and it updates the **LastActivity field** (`DateTime`) in the database. (In fact It updates this filed every 10 seconds.)

Now I have to detect that this application works **N time interval so I can stop it**.

Is it possible to implement using only one filed or I have to add some extra methods/code/DB fields? Or even I have to create some Windows Service that checks this field and etc?

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will definately need something more - 
simplest solution i see is adding another column for example ActivityTimeInSeconds

Then after services recieves update request you do this(semi-pseudo):

```
Dim ddiff as integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Second,LastActivityField,Now)
If ddiff<20 then ''// if 20seconds not passed since last update recieved
   ActivityTimeInSeconds+=ddiff ''//add interval from last update to 
Else
   ActivityTimeInSeconds=0 ''//reset this if itivity was longer before this request
End If
LastActivityField = Now
```